# HTML & Session problems

Tags: php, html

Not working !

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<p class="username"><?php print $_SESSION['name']; ?></p>
```

Comment: I assume you started the Session and set `$_SESSION['name']` elsewhere? You should have done that *after* `session_start` as well.

Comment: Did you fill `$_SESSION['name']` with some data?

Comment: @Digital: You are asking questions with very short info If you explain your question well you will get better answer

Comment: -1: Next time consider putting some effort on your question. Your code is valid and will throw no errors so, the least you could write is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @andre valid apart from the undefined array index error

Comment: @dogmatic69: Only if `$_SESSION['name']` was not defined previously... And you can't tell for sure from the code posted.

Comment: and you know it was. if we making assumptions, how about the fact that session_start() was called after half a page of html has been put out?

Comment: @andrematos: If it were defined, this question would not have been asked.

Comment: @Tomalak: So you are saying that the value of `$_SESSION['name']` cannot be an empty string?

Comment: @andrematos: Well OK, that's a possible case. :) Without knowing what "not working !" means to DiGiTAL_DOMAiN, we're all just guessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = 'Hello World!';
?>
<p class="username"><?php print $_SESSION['name']; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is an array made available to the current user and its members are referred to as you would any other array. Therefore, using your example, if you have not already defined $_SESSION['name'] then it will not show you anything helpful.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare and insert a value into `$_SESSION['name']`, and you can print it 
as follows:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = 'asht';
?>
<p class="class1"><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></p>
```

In your case the result didn't display anything because `$_SESSION['name']` was empty.